# How to get old value and new value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2

I have a table grid, which is editable using Javascript, when I click on that particular field. I can change the value and update the old value.

How can I get old value and also the new value for logging purposes?

```
<s:iterator var="posting" value="PostLookup">
    <tr class="update-rel">                             
        <td id="${post.Id}"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="alignleft">${post.coin}</td>                                 
        <td class="alignleft" >${post.rate}</td>                                        
        <td class="alignleft">${posting.trainCode}</td>
        <td class="alignleft"><fmt:formatDate pattern="HH:mm" value="${posting.postTime}" /></td>
        <td class="alignleft">${posting.payMode}</td>
        <td class="alignleft">${posting.payModeSub}</td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

**JavaScript** Making rows editable

```
     function activateTableEditing() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var rowIndex;
        var columnIndex;

        // get dynamic values from the server through a json call to be displayed inside the drop down box
        var jsonObject = getJSONObject('ajax/fetchpayMode.action', 'Pay Modes');
        var payModes = jsonObject.payModes;

        $('#tablePostLookup tbody td').on('click', function(e) {

            rowIndex = $(this).parent().index('#tablePostLookup tbody tr');
            columnIndex = $(this).index('#tablePostLookup tbody tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ') td');
          //console.log('Row ' + rowIndex + ' and column ' + columnIndex + ' is clicked ...');

            if (columnIndex == 2 || columnIndex == 3 || columnIndex == 4) {
                editInputBox(e, $(this).parent(), rowIndex, columnIndex);
            }
            if (columnIndex == 5) {
                editCombobox(e, $(this).parent(), rowIndex, columnIndex, payMode);
            }
            if (columnIndex == 6) {
                var payModes = $(this).parent().children('td:eq(5)').text();
                jsonObject = getJSONObject('ajax/fetchpayModeSub.action?payModeSub=' + payMode, 'paymode sub ');
                var paymentModeSub = jsonObject.paymentModeSub;
                editCombobox(e, $(this).parent(), rowIndex, columnIndex, paymentModeSub);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Getting current values - When update button is clicked.

```
function savePostLookup(e, action) {

var countRowSelected = 0;
$('#tablePostLookup tbody tr').each(function() {
    var result = $(this).children('td').eq(0).children('input[type=checkbox]').eq(0).is(':checked');
    if (result) {
        ++countRowSelected;
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var id = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').eq(0).attr('id');
        var coin = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
        var rate = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
        var trainCode = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text();
        var postTime = $(this).find('td:eq(4)').text();
        var payMode = $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text();
        var payModeSub = $(this).find('td:eq(6)').text();

        createJSONObject(id, coin, rate, trainCode, postTime, payMode, payModeSub);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you could potentially do. Create an object with the following key values pair.

```
{
  "td1": [
    {
      "oldVlaue": "old",
      "newValue": "new"
    }
  ],
  "td2": [
    {
      "oldVlaue": "old1",
      "newValue": "new1"
    }
  ]
}
```

So each time you click on some a table value, you can get the value from the **`event.target`** and you can also get which table element is clicked. Just update the value in your JSON object with the values you get.

As I said, this could potenitally be a way to keep track of the old or new values. Feel free to try something different or better.